Does any Artin Braid group come from a Braid group of a root system?
An Artin Braid group of $n$-strands can be seen as the fundamental group of the $n^{\text{th}}$ (unordered) configuration space $\pi_1(\mathbb C^n\setminus \cup H_{ij})/S_n)$, where $H_{ij}=Z(x_i-x_j)$ is an hyperplane.
More generally, a Braid group of a root system is defined as follows: Fix a root system corresponding to a finite-dimensional Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$. The braid group $\text{Br}$ of a root system is defined as $\pi_1((\mathfrak h\setminus \mathfrak h_\alpha)/W)$, where $\mathfrak h$ is the Cartan Lie subalgebra, $W$ is the Weyl group and $\mathfrak h_\alpha$ are the root hyperplanes corresponding to all roots.
I know $S_n$ is the Weyl group of $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb C)$, but the Cartan Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb C)$ has rank $n-1$, not $\mathbb C^n$. So an Artin Braid group $B(n)$ is not the Braid group of the root system of $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb C)$. My question is: does every Artin Braid group $B(n)$ come from the Braid group of a root system of some Lie group's Lie algebra?

@QiaochuYuan I think $\mathfrak{sl}(n+1,\mathbb C)$ has Cartan Lie algebra $\mathbb C^n$ but Weyl group $S_{n+1}$. So the Braid group for  $\mathfrak{sl}(n+1,\mathbb C)$  is $\pi_1((\mathbb C^n\setminus \cup H)/S_{n+1}))$ not the $Br(n)$, right?

There actually isn't an issue here, you get $B_n$ as the braid group of $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{C})$. This is because $\mathbb{C}^n \setminus H$ has an $S_n$-equivariant deformation retraction onto the subspace of points such that $x_1 + \dots + x_n = 0$, given by
$$(x_1, \dots x_n) \mapsto (x_1, \dots x_n) - t \frac{x_1 + \dots + x_n}{n} (1, 1, \dots )$$
for $t \in [0, 1]$. So the two have the same fundamental group, even after the quotient by $S_n$, which is $B_n$.
